# Angular await service between components, Behavior Subject

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an issue in my Angular web store when i refresh the window, i create a service that takes the user data from the server and then inject to the 'products' section with BehaviorSubject, my goal is to make just one request to the server:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  private userId = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
  currentUserId = this.userId.asObservable();

  constructor() { }
  
  sendUserId(message: string){
    this.userId.next(message)
  }
}
```

This works fine but the problem is when i refresh the window in products section, in console i can see that the service takes the user data but when i getProducts() it throws an error, it seems like getProducts() makes the request before the service had the response, i need the user Id to make the products request. My question: Is there a way to await the response of BehaviorSubject and then make the getProducts() request?. This is the code in the products section:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._dataService.currentUserId.subscribe(userId => this.userId = userId);

    if(this.userId.length === 0){
      this.userService.getUserProfile().subscribe(
        res => {
          this.userDetails = res['user'];
          this.userId = this.userDetails._id;
          this.getProducts();          
        },
        err => { 
          console.log(err);           
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.getProducts();
    } 
  }
```

As you can see, i do a condition to check if userId exists, if not i have to make a new user request, this fix the bug but i think there's a better way to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at my library ez-state https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vbpzem?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fusers.service.ts

Comment: I haven't written any documentation for it yet but this article on the library it replaces goes over the concepts https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Comment: Thanks!, I'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

How about placing all your logic within the `observer`'s `next` function as below:

```js
this._dataService.currentUserId.subscribe(userId => {
  if (userId.length === 0)
  {
    this.userService.getUserProfile().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.userDetails = res['user'];
        this.userId = this.userDetails._id;
        this.getProducts();
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  } else
  {
    this.getProducts();
  }
});
```