# await dataService between components Angular, Behavior Subject

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a Behavior Subject dataService in Angular that makes a request to server to get the user details when admin-layout-component loads (parent component), and then injects the data in the user component, this is my user component onInit:

```js
ngOnInit(){
    this._dataService.currentUserDetails.subscribe(userDetails => this.userDetails = userDetails);
    console.log(this.userDetails);

    if(this.userDetails === ''){
      this.getUser();
    }
   
}
```

[image: Console]

When i refresh the browser in user component, first loads the current component ngOnInit, i have to make the conditional to check userDetails and make a new request to server, but admin-layout-component is making the request too, my question: There is a way to await the dataService so i don't have to make the getUser() twice?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `BehaviourSubject`?

Comment: Yes, i did another question about this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63367607/angular-await-service-between-components-behavior-subject

Answer (score 1):

You can use Subject to store information about user and if you need, you always get data from subject by `this.userDetails` anywhere in you component:

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
  userDetails$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

 ngOnInit(){
    this._dataService.currentUserDetails.subscribe(userDetails => {
      this.userDetails.next(userDetails)
    });
 }

 get userDetails(): any {
   return this.userDetails$.getValue();
 }
}
```

and in template you can subscribe to your service Subject

```
  <div> {{ userDetails$ | async }} </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, userDetails in console logs: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: BehaviorSubject}, the user data is in value Observable, i try to access ._value but i cant access.

Comment: i need to store the object user data in a variable